# Delay the execution of an expressJS method for 30 days or more

Tags: node.js, express

Can the execution of an expressJS method be delayed for 30 days or more just by using setTimeout ?

Let's say I want to create an endpoint /sendMessage that send a message to my other app after a timeout of 30 days. Will my expressJS method execution will last long time enough to fire this message after this delay ?

Comment: No. And you should not ever need to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans How can I programmatically schedule the execution of an API request (just once) at a pre-defined date ? I saw node-cron and this is not exactly what I need. Any suggestion ?

Comment: yeah: don't use node, use _actual_ cron to trigger the dedicated script(s) that runs the code you need to run once a month, once a month. No reason to do this "in the server itself", because as a server, you can make it do whatever you need it to do based on an API call originating from the local machine's IP (and nowhere else).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Is it possible to manually trigger (on demand) a cron job at a specific timestamp (e.g. milliseconds) and execute it only once ? I don't want repetition

Comment: if you only need it once, why do you need automation at all? Just set a google reminder and run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If your server runs continuously for 30 days or more, then `setTimeout()` will work for that.  But, it is probably not smart to rely on that fact that your server never, ever has to restart.

There are 3rd party programs/modules designed explicitly for this.  If you don't want to use one of them, then what I have done in the past is I write each future firing time into a JSON file and I set a timer for it with `setTimeout()`.  If the timer successfully fires, then I remove that time from the JSON file.

So, at any point in time, the JSON file always contains a list of times in the future that I want timers to fire for.  Any timer that fires is immediately removed from the JSON file.

Anytime my server starts up, I read the times from the JSON file and reconfigure the `setTimeout()` for each one.

This way, even if my server restarts, I won't lose any of the timers.

In case you were wondering, the way nodejs creates timers, it does not cost you anything to have a bunch of future timers configured.  Nodejs keeps the timers in a sorted linked list and the event loop just checks the time for the next timer to fire - the one at the front of the sorted list (the rest of the timers are not looked at until they get to the front of the sorted list).  This means the only time it costs anything to have lots of future timers is when inserting a new timer into the sorted list and there is no regular cost in the event loop to having lots of pending timers present.